# Wordpress - Why I get 411 Length required error?

Tags: wordpress

since some days ago I got an error if I try to update menues and some pages.
I get a white Page with 411 requiered length error.
Never had this before.
Wordpress 5.8 and before.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have downloadle links in the menu? maybe for `.pdf` or something similar?

Comment: No. Everything was clear writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you gave BitDefender activated. It seems to have received some kind of an update that blocks some requests. I had this issue with my website too, also with several others and disabling Protection Shield solved the issue.

Comment: Oh, SUPER. It was the Problem with Bitdefender. Thanks 1000 times!!!

Comment: @GuntherStallmann dont forget to mark as solved :) I also contacted BitDefender support, let them know about the issue. We are not alone, my hosting provider said that they also received quite a few complaints from their clients about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bitdefender is the problem. But I tried other AV programs to compare, including Windows Defender and Avast, and the problem does not exist with them. This seems to be a BD-specific issue, which I hope someone will fix. I like Bitdefender (Free), but this is really a nuisance. It's also theoretically dangerous to suspend malware protection.